# Errors in chrome/ ie redirecting to facebook app from fan page

Tags: facebook, facebook-iframe

I'm a little confused here.  The basic problem is on my fan page when I click on the icon for the app I made it works fine in firefox, but in IE I get the error "This content cannot be displayed in a frame" and in chrome it just never opens the app and goes blank.  This has happened to me on the facebook profile I created the app with as well as a test account.  The weird thing is that on my other facebook account it works perfectly fine on all browsers.  The app also works when directly gone to from search or recent apps. I recently changed the name of the app and security id and reconnected it to my page.  Under app settings my tab urls are correct. The code at the top of my canvas page consists of:

```
<?php       
$app_id = "181247898619054";
$app_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$my_url = "https://apps.facebook.com/wellnessq/";
session_register();
session_start();


if (!isset($_REQUEST["code"]))
{
 $_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)); //CSRF protection
 $dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
   . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&scope=email&state="
   . $_SESSION['state'];

 echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
exit;
}
$code = $_REQUEST['code'];
{
  $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
   . "client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
   . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret . "&code=" . $code;

 $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
 $params = null;
  parse_str($response, $params);

  $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" 
   . $params['access_token'];

  $user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));
 }

?>
```

Any ideas? If you want to see the errors yourself just let me know and I'll post where to find them.  Thanks.

Comment: I am curious if Chrome doesn't like the injection of a scripted redirect, it could easily confuse that with a hijack attempt and drop it, or show an error.

Comment: The real weird part is that it only happens on one of my facebook accounts, the other one works perfectly normal on all browsers. I deleted all cookies and tried again, but no success.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a PHP header to redirect to your link?

```
header( 'Location: http://www.yoursite.com/new_page.html' ) ;
```

Comment: yeah, that didn't work. It's so strange because it works from the app list from the facebook homepage but something about when it goes to the app from the fan page is not allowed.  This problem didn't use to exist.